# chrome extension witn icon on right edge/sliding from right side

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am building a Chrome extension that will present some stats in a popup window after clickig. I was wondering if it is possible to place a button/icon in the middle on the right edge of Chrome browser (not on the upper tab), so that after clicking a new tab/bar with statistics will slide from right/appear (height of a window should be equal to height of a browser window).

Is it possible? If not how about Chrome App ?

Thanks,

Tomasz

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You would need to set it up by loading CSS/JS/HTML into the loaded-page's markup

Comment: Thanks. Finally I found out that HTML/CSS/JS code can be injected into loaded page using content scripts.

Comment: Great job! Feel free to "answer" yourself here with some sample code so it can help others in the future :)

Comment: I'll do it right now, maybe someone will benefit from it ;)